# Topology on $[0,1]$ that makes it pseudocompact but not compact?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness

The space $[0,1]$ is compact with respect to its usual (metric) topology. I was wondering whether there is a known topology on it which makes it pseudocompact but not compact? Now sequentially compact and countably compact both imply pseudocompact so any such topology would work as well. Also, a metric space which is pseudocompact is automatically compact, so the topology cannot be induced by a metric. Any idea or reference would be appreciated.

I know we can always find such a topology. For instance, if we consider a pseudocompact space which is not compact which has the same cardinality as $[0,1]$ and transfer the topology to $[0,1]$ via bijection. I wanted to know if there is one which is frequently discussed and/or easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the topology on $[0,1]$ consisting of the empty set and of the sets containing $0$. Then every continuous function $f: [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ is constant, and thus $[0,1]$ is pseudocompact but not compact. Indeed, if $f(x) \not= f(0)$, there exists an open interval $I$ containing $f(x)$ but not $f(0)$. But since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(I)$ is open, and hence contains $0$, a contradiction.

Comment: The Long Segment. Consider the cardinal ordinal $\omega_1$. Let $S=\omega_1\times [0,1)$ with the lexicographic (dictionary) order $<_S$ and the order-topology on $S$ induced by $<_S.$ Right now I am too tired to go into detail.

Comment: Is it a comment to my answer or to the question?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: It doesn’t appear to be either, since it has no natural embedding in $[0,1]$. I do wonder, though, whether the OP is one of those people who require pseudocompact spaces to be Tikhonov.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No I don't :)

Comment: I mis-placed it. It is meant to comment to the Q.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott . The OP does not ask for a "natural" embedding other than any bijection.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: The OP explicitly **excludes** such embeddings.