# When is an initial topology pseudocompact?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

In my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3969677/topology-on-0-1-that-makes-it-pseudocompact-but-not-compact/3969762#3969762) I asked if there are well-known topologies on $[0,1]$ that make it pseudocompact, but not compact. For that I was now considering initial topologies on $[0,1]$. Suppose I have the functions $f_i:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and I consider the smallest topology on $[0,1]$ with respect to which each $f_i$ is continuous. For this topology to be necessarily pseudocompact, I take each $f_i$ to be bounded. Is there any way to tell whether each function continuous in this topology will be bounded?

Answer (score 1):

Take the topology generated by $\{(1/n,1]:n\in\mathbb Z^+\}\cup\{0\}$, under this topology $[0,1]$ is not compact and it is pseudo compact:

Take a continuous function (under the new topology) $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ and two points $x\in(0,1]$ then if $f(x)\neq f(1)$ there would be an open set $B$ containing $f(x)$ but not $f(1)$ so $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ but $1\notin f^{-1}(B)$ which is impossible so $f|_{(0,1]}$ is constant so $\text{im}(f)=\{f(0),f(1)\}$.